# How to export/import a only a type definition in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-only-import-export

How can I export and import a type definition independently from the module itself.

In flowtype this would look like this:
The file `sub.js` export the type `myType` using `export type myType = {id: number};` and the file `main.js` imports the type using `import type {myType} from './sub.js';`

Comment: what's the problem with Typescrypt ?

Comment: I don't understand how to import the type (in flowtype `import type {myType} from './sub.js';`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just import it normally and the compiler works out that you don't need the import statement emitted because no concrete code is used.

Here's an example:

component.ts

```
export interface MyInterface {
    name: string;
}
```

app.ts

```
import { MyInterface } from './component';

class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    constructor(public name: string) { }
}
```

The app.*js* file is simply (ES2015 version):

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Or in older ES5 terms:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var MyClass = /** @class */ (function () {
    function MyClass(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    return MyClass;
}());
```

The important thing here is that the TypeScript compiler has worked out that the import is only needed at compile time, not runtime.

Answer (score 9):

Typescript 3.8 and later has type only exports and imports:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-8/#type-only-imports-exports

```
import type { SomeThing } from "./some-module.js";

export type { SomeThing };
```